# Return first match row from subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a scenario in which my subquery returns 4 rows. Within the result of the sub query I need to run a case to match certain conditions and have only one row (the first match) returned as a result my outer query.

I am doing the following but all rows matching the conditions are returned. I need to just get the first match.

```
select result.place_id, result.person_id,result.first_name,result.last_name, result.personskill, result.cost_center, result.work_center,result.placeskill
from
(select place.place_id, person.person_id,person.first_name,person.last_name, person.user_def2 as work_center, person.user_def3 as cost_center, place.user_def5 as placeskill,
place_person.person_relationship as personskill,'' as specialCustomer,place.tenant_id
 from person 
 left outer join place_person on person.person_id= place_person.person_id and person.tenant_id = place_person.tenant_id
 left outer join place on place_person.place_id = place.place_id and place_person.tenant_id = place.tenant_id     
 where place.place_id = '0004587287') as result
where 1 = CASE
WHEN (result.placeskill = 'INDUSTRIAL' AND result.personskill = 'FST' AND result.person_id != 'NOREP' AND result.person_id is not null) THEN 1  
WHEN (result.placeskill = 'INDUSTRIAL' AND result.personskill = 'AUT_DIS' AND result.person_id != 'NOREP' AND result.person_id is not null) THEN 1 
WHEN (result.placeskill = 'INDUSTRIAL' AND result.personskill = 'SUB_CON' AND result.person_id != 'NOREP' AND result.person_id is not null) THEN 1 
WHEN (result.placeskill = 'COMMERCIAL' AND result.personskill = 'CST' AND result.person_id != 'NOREP' AND result.person_id is not null) THEN 1 
WHEN (result.placeskill = 'COMMERCIAL' AND (result.personskill = 'CST' AND result.person_id = 'NOREP') AND (result.personskill = 'FST' AND result.person_id != 'NOREP' AND result.person_id is not null)) THEN 1 
WHEN (result.placeskill = 'COMMERCIAL' AND (result.personskill = 'CST' AND result.person_id = 'NOREP') AND (result.personskill = 'FST' AND result.person_id = 'NOREP') AND (result.personskill = 'AUT_DIS' AND result.person_id != 'NOREP' AND result.person_id is not null)) THEN 1 
WHEN (result.placeskill = 'COMMERCIAL' AND (result.personskill = 'CST' AND result.person_id = 'NOREP') AND (result.personskill = 'FST' AND result.person_id = 'NOREP') AND (result.personskill = 'AUT_DIS' AND result.person_id = 'NOREP') AND (result.personskill = 'SUB_CON' AND result.person_id != 'NOREP' AND result.person_id is not null)) THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: I think posting some sample data and expected result in tabular format will help you get an answer faster. You can set up examples with [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Either an `APPLY` or a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function are likely needed, but as the query is shown, it's too much effort to go through it all. If you want a good answer, spend some time editing to make this easier to read.